Adding Fiscal Years to Tableau Cloud
Tableau desktop allows you to define fiscal year starts and I use this function in pretty much ever significant report I built.  Tableau Cloud lacks this ability.  I can, and have, created manual groups to achieve this but as dates are added into the database this falls apart.  Is there a way i can automate this so i can build reports/dashboards that dont require manual intervention to maintain fiscal years?
as mentioned above I have used a manual hack by creating a group, but this requires intervention whenever I update it.

I'm not familiar with Cloud other than knowing it doesn't offer all the features of Desktop.  Are you able to add a data source with fiscal years?  It would be helpful if you gave an example of "created manual groups to achieve this but as dates are added into the database this falls apart" -- like, what is the formula and how does it "fall apart" as dates are added to the data source?  You can edit your question and add these details.
